# nuget package of RCL not working in some projects

Tags: nuget, razor-class-library

I Built a Razor Class Library which was exported to a nuget package to be shared among my netcore mvc projects. I just noticed that it did not work in one of my projects (Let's call it PPM).

The funtion of the RCL is very simple. After installed, visit http://yourSite/SeaiApiSimple/GetSeai and you will see a json (just like what swagger ui does). But in PPM, installing the nuget is perfect but the url leads to 404 error.

The code of the nuget looks like:

```
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace SeaiApiSimple;

[Route("[controller]/{action}")]
[ApiController]
public class SeaiApiSimpleController : ControllerBase
{
    public string GetSeai()
    {
        return SeaiReflectorSimple.ToJson(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()!);
    }
}
```

All the projects are nearly the same, netcore 6.0 mvc, mongo db, etc, sharing code with about 20 class libraries and razor class libraries. The PPM project was the first finished and all the others were copied and modified from it (changing name, port, etc).

Part of the PPM.csprj file looks like (SeaiApiSimple is the nuget package):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">    
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework> 
        <UserSecretsId>aspnet-ColorAdmin-1F5D3C4F-0890-4CC7-9F09-68A81047D315</UserSecretsId> 
     <CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory> true</CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>
    <copytooutputdirectory>Always</copytooutputdirectory>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

LanchingSettings.json of PPM:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:27000",
      "sslPort": 44370
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
      }
    },
    "AdaPMM": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
      },
          "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:28701;http://localhost:28700"
    }
  }
}
```

It's nearly the same of other projects, except the port number. Btw since there was an iis problem (canot start iis express) from time to time, so I debug from project name (AdaPPM) rather than iisexpress. But this is happening in all projects, not just in AdaPPM.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the package for many times, no error occurred during installing but it just did not work.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks a lot.
And if you need more information, feel free to tell me. And thanks again.